# How to read a file on paste event in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

In HTML5 we know that we can read files using predefined API. As of now I have tried

`<input type="file">` and the `File Drop` method. They have worked fine for me.

But I want to know the possibility of pasting a file on a div and capturing the file on paste.
For Example

```
 $('#dummyDIV').bind('paste',function()
 {
      // Like var file = files[0]
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: well, in theory, the clipboard can contain files too, so you should be able to access them in the same way that you do in the drop method. try to console.log() the event object and navigate through it to see if the property exists and the path that you have to take to get to it.

Comment: Should be possible, this site reads files on paste with the exact same method that is used on drop: http://base64img.com/ - however that is done by pasting an online adress into a textbox, and I'm not sure if it works by pasting a file onto the dropzone?

Answer (score 18):

You can only read the file name of pasted file.

http://jsfiddle.net/vdNFR/

```
$('body').bind('paste', function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a.originalEvent.clipboardData);
    console.log(a.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('File'));
    console.log(a.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
    if (a.originalEvent.clipboardData.files[0]) console.log(a.originalEvent.clipboardData.files[0].getAsFile());
    if (a.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[0]) console.log(a.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile());
    console.log(a, b, c);
});
```

It would be a major security hole if any browser would allow this situation to happen.

Comment: Just curious to know why it would be a security hole. Can you explain?

Comment: Accidents cause harm. Agreed. And one has to pay for the mistakes done. Let's say I'm not a dumb user to play around with a KeePass file, what other security problems can it cause?

Comment: What the hell. You're all talking about accidentally *dropping* the file on browser. Files can be Drag&Dropped any time on browser and many applications (like facebook) handle them for upload. This question is about **pasting**.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer, if this would be a security issue, the browser should not allow drag and drop too. But it allows drag'n'drop and it doesn't allow copy/paste. It does not make too much sense, isn't it?
And you cannot even read the file name of the pasted file. I did not tried in jQuery, but pure javascript.

Comment: @lukyer Nope, in 2020 `ctrlv.cz` still only supports screenshots, not files...

Comment: @lukyer Files, not images. It doesn't work like `<input type=file>` where any file can be used, it works like Paint or GIMP, where you're only able to paste images. Pasting files into other applications (like a chat) works fine, so it's an intentional limitation by browsers. The site you promoted as being able to do file pasting, can't do file pasting. Frankly, I'm wondering if you are just promoting the site or if you genuinely thought this solved an issue, seeing as the site is commercial (it runs advertisements) and you seem to be the owner but didn't disclose that.