# Paste file into web page from Windows explorer

Tags: javascript, clipboarddata

I'm trying to paste a file from Windows Explorer into a web page. When accessing `event.clipboardData` `items`, `files` and `types` are all empty.

If I take a screenshot (Ctrl+PrintScrn) or copy a plain text and then paste into the web page, `items` and `types` are populated just fine.

I attached the paste event on window. I'm using latest Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578136/how-to-read-a-file-on-paste-event-in-html5

Comment: That is in jQuery, my question is for pure javascript.

Comment: Just change `$('body').bind('paste', function(a, b, c) {` to `document.body.addEventListener('paste', function(a, b, c) {`, the rest of the code is already pure JS ;)

Comment: It's not about jquery/pure javascript.. Do browsers support paste **from windows file explorer**?